# useEffect hook isn't triggered inside ReactDOMServer.renderToString()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/) and [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) libraries to create a map inside a [React Js](https://reactjs.org/) app as well as [Material UI](https://mui.com/) library for the core UI components.

I'm creating a custom cluster and marker components (using React component, not using image/icon file) for the cluster and marker inside the map. I'm using [react-leaflet-markercluster](https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster) for the custom cluster feature and the pie chart from [Apache Echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) library for the custom cluster component.

##### Problem

The problem I'm facing is the `useEffect` hook inside my `CustomCluster` component is never triggered.

#### Steps to produce

1. Run the playground here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-custom-cluster-react-leaflet-s2wwsh
2. This is the initial state
   [image]
3. Press the zoom out button (top left corner)
   [image]
   We can see that the 3 markers become a single cluster. The console prints the `cluster` value from the `CustomCluster` component but there is no "update chart" message. It means that the `useEffect` hook is not triggered.
4. Press again the zoom out button
   [image]
   We can see that all 4 markers become a single cluster. The console prints the updated `cluster` value from the `CustomCluster` component but again there is no "update chart" message. It means that the `useEffect` hook is not triggered again.

#### Code

App.jsx

```js
const customClusterIcon = (cluster, dummyLocationList) => {
  return L.divIcon({
    // className: 'marker-cluster-custom',
    // html: `<span>${cluster.getChildCount()}</span>`,
    // iconSize: L.point(40, 40, true),
    className: "custom-icon",
    html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
          <CustomCluster cluster={cluster} locationList={dummyLocationList} />
        </StyledEngineProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  });
};

<MarkerClusterGroup
  showCoverageOnHover={false}
  spiderfyDistanceMultiplier={2}
  iconCreateFunction={(cluster) =>
    customClusterIcon(cluster, dummyLocationList)
  }
>
  {dummyLocationList.map((item, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      position={[item.latitude, item.longitude]}
      icon={L.divIcon({
        className: "custom-icon",
        html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
              <CustomMarker
                movingStatus={item.status}
                label={item.deviceName}
              />
            </StyledEngineProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        )
      })}
    />
  ))}
</MarkerClusterGroup>
```

CustomCluster.jsx

```js
const CustomCluster = (props) => {
  const { cluster, locationList } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const chartRef = useRef();

  let clusterLocationList = [];
  cluster.getAllChildMarkers().forEach((itemCluster) => {
    locationList.forEach((itemLocation) => {
      if (
        itemCluster._latlng.lat === itemLocation.latitude &&
        itemCluster._latlng.lng === itemLocation.longitude
      )
        clusterLocationList.push(itemLocation);
    });
  });

  const chartOption = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "Access From",
        type: "pie",
        radius: ["40%", "70%"],
        avoidLabelOverlap: false,
        label: {
          show: true,
          position: "inner"
        },
        labelLine: {
          show: false
        },
        data: [
          { value: 1048, name: "Search Engine" },
          { value: 735, name: "Direct" },
          { value: 580, name: "Email" },
          { value: 484, name: "Union Ads" },
          { value: 300, name: "Video Ads" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("update chart");

    let chart;
    if (chartRef.current !== null) chart = init(chartRef.current);

    const resizeChart = () => {
      chart?.resize();
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeChart);

    if (chartRef.current !== null) {
      const chart = getInstanceByDom(chartRef.current);
      chart.setOption(chartOption);
    }

    return () => {
      chart?.dispose();
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeChart);
    };
  }, [cluster]);

  console.log(cluster);

  return (
    <>
      {/* AVATAR */}
      <Avatar>{cluster.getChildCount()}</Avatar>

      {/* PIE CHART */}
      <Box className={classes.chartContainer}>
        <Box ref={chartRef} className={classes.chart} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomCluster;
```

##### Question

Based on some articles on the internet, the `useEffect` hook is not triggered on React server-side render (SSR) for example here https://codewithhugo.com/react-useeffect-ssr/.

So what's the solution for this case?

The goal is to create a custom cluster feature using a pie chart.
Here is the sample http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728 but it uses [Vanilla Js](http://vanilla-js.com/), not [React Js](https://reactjs.org/).

Comment: `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` will just return html, no js. So the useEffect in CustomCluster will never trigger. Move up that logic

Comment: You're right. Do you have any working solution for this case?